# Unsafe pointer becoming corrupted

Tags: rust, unsafe

I am trying to get a better understanding of unsafe pointers in Rust. In the code below, I am creating a tree where each node points back to its parent. When I create a leaf and add it as a child to a node, everything looks fine. Once I take that node and add it to another node, the leaf's parent pointer becomes corrupted. Why is the leaf's parent pointer becoming corrupted, while the middle node's parent pointer is fine? What changes would make it work?

```
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Shape<'a> {
    pub id: usize,
    pub parent: Option<*mut Group<'a>>,
}

type Node<'a> = Box<Group<'a>>;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Group<'a> {
    pub shape: Shape<'a>,
    pub children: Vec<Node<'a>>,
}

pub struct GroupBuilder<'a> {
    id: usize,
    children: Vec<Node<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> GroupBuilder<'a> {
    pub fn new(id: usize) -> GroupBuilder<'a> {
        GroupBuilder {
            id,
            children: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn build(&self) -> Node<'a> {
        unsafe {
            let group: *mut Group = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Group {
                shape: Shape {
                    id: self.id,
                    parent: Option::None,
                },
                children: self.children.clone(),
            }));

            for child in (*group).children.iter_mut() {
                child.shape.parent = Option::Some(group.clone());
            }

            Box::from_raw(group)
        }
    }

    pub fn add_child(&mut self, child: Node<'a>) -> &mut GroupBuilder<'a> {
        self.children.push(child);
        self
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    unsafe {

        // THIS WORKS!
        let leaf = GroupBuilder::new(1).build();

        assert_eq!(leaf.shape.id, 1);
        assert_eq!(leaf.shape.parent, Option::None);

        // THIS WORKS AS WELL!
        let node = GroupBuilder::new(2).add_child(leaf).build();

        assert_eq!(node.shape.id, 2);
        assert_eq!(node.children[0].shape.id, 1);
        assert_eq!((*node.children[0].shape.parent.unwrap()).shape.id, 2);

        // THIS WORKS FOR ROOT -> NODE, BUT BREAKS ON ROOT -> NODE -> X
        let root = GroupBuilder::new(3).add_child(node).build();

        assert_eq!(root.shape.id, 3);
        assert_eq!(root.shape.parent, Option::None);
        assert_eq!(root.children[0].shape.id, 2);
        assert_eq!((*root.children[0].shape.parent.unwrap()).shape.id, 3);
        assert_eq!(root.children[0].children[0].shape.id, 1);

        // THINGS BREAK HERE!
        assert_eq!(
            (*root.children[0].children[0].shape.parent.unwrap())
                .shape
                .id,
            2
        );
    } 
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.54s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `93906121591344`,
 right: `2`', src/main.rs:77:9
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ceade48020a4172a0ce24a9c1ac8c066).

Comment: Note that `Option<raw_ptr>` is usually redundant, since raw pointers can be null.

Comment: Also: `Option::None` and `Option::Some` can be spelled as just `None` and `Some`; the `group.clone()` in `build()` is unecessary (raw pointers are `Copy`).

Comment: Why is the lifetime?

Comment: [Here's a cleaned up version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58cbc5280a7204b8e41f2ee913e34f49).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `self.children.clone()` inside `build`. Let's follow step-by-step what happens when you create `root`:

- Temporary `GroupBuilder` is created (let's name it `tmp`).
- `node` is moved into `tmp.children`.
- `tmp.children` is cloned, the clone is put into `root.children`. Since `node` is a `Box`, it is cloned too.
- Being temporary, `tmp` is dropped at the end of statement, so `tmp.children` is dropped, so `node` is deallocated, and pointer in `leaf` becomes dangling.

By allowing `build` to take ownership of `GroupBuilder`, we can make the final assertion succeed - [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e850eb44744f42b3aaf6a3b60a5769bf) (note that I've also changed `add_child`'s signature from `&mut Self -> &mut Self` to `Self -> Self`, so that chaining is still available).

---

Note however, that this code example is still treated as UB by Miri - it probably thinks that you can't move the `Box` when there's a pointer pointing to the insides of the `Box`. This might be a limitation of Miri, but it's also possible that you are indeed doing something unsound.